# error in scala while creating dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

getting error  `unclosed string literal`

code :

```
val relianceDF = relianceRDD.map(rel => {
 (rel.split(",")(0).toInt,
  rel.split(",")(1),
  rel.split(",')(2),
  rel.split(",")(3).toInt,
  rel.split(",")(4))
 }).toDF
```

Comment: Question not understandable. what is your `relianceRDD` type and what is your expected output ?

Comment: The question is more or less understandable: the OP wants to get rid of the abovementioned error. That's the wrong close reason. The right close reason is "Offtopic -> trivial typographical error".

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the following line

```
rel.split(",')(2),
```

you have used `'` instead of `"`

Comment: my pleasure @FayazKhan, you can accept the answer if it helped you :) and an upvote when you would be able to